# iOS Launch Screen Cuts into Splash Animation

Tags: ios

I have a splash animation that is being cut into for the first ~0.4 seconds by the launch screen. I do not want to remove the launch screen. I was wondering if I could set the splash animation to play only after the launch screen closes. I would rather not hardcode a delay of 0.4 seconds if possible, as it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The best place to do so is in your main view controller's viewWillAppear method. You can put a trigger in there or launch the animation directly. Hardcoding a delay is indeed not a good idea because besides device configuration like processor speed etc there are a lot of other contributing factors to the time the launch screen takes.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. This is already how I implemented it.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide that detail about your implementation. 
A technique that I have used successfully in the past positions a png image across the main view controller. It is taken from the first frame of the animation to be played. The animation is then triggered in viewDidAppear where we can be sure that the launch image is gone and simultaneously the png is hidden. A bit tricky to position everything exactly for all devices, but it works like a charm and doesn't involve any timers.